# Vee-validate extend validation with 3rd party library

Tags: vee-validate

I tried to validate a phone number field using [vee-validate](https://vee-validate.logaretm.com/v3) and [awesome-phonenumber](https://www.npmjs.com/package/awesome-phonenumber) but even I enter a correct value, error from validation still showing up. Also did check the value from console but still error message is thrown.

```
import { extend } from 'vee-validate'
import PhoneNumber from 'awesome-phonenumber'

extend('phone_number', {
  message () {
    return  'This field is not a valid phone number'
  },
  validate (value) {
    let phone = new PhoneNumber(value)
    if(phone.isValid() && phone.getRegionCode() === 'AU') {
      console.log(phone.getRegionCode()) // this is true but error message still showing
    } else {
      console.log('not valid')
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return `true` in your vee-validate rules, I don't see you returning anything which means `undefined` and vee-validate treats `undefined` the same as `false.

```js
import { extend } from 'vee-validate'
import PhoneNumber from 'awesome-phonenumber'

extend('phone_number', {
  message () {
    return  'This field is not a valid phone number'
  },
  validate (value) {
    let phone = new PhoneNumber(value)
    if(phone.isValid() && phone.getRegionCode() === 'AU') {
      return true;
    }

    return false;
  }
})
```

Comment: yes correct. I was focusing on the value returned from the console.log. lol thanks. fyi already got it working by the way. thanks